# How to add influential factors in PCA with Bray-Curtis Index without using the BiodiversityR package in R?

Tags: r, macos, pca, vegan

I am trying to add loading, or the influential species for the PCOA plot that I have. I calculated the Bray Curtis distance matrix to plot the oordination. Now, I want to add the loadings to determine the most influential species. However, I am unable to use the `BiodiversityR` package as Mac OS requires to install the `tcl-tk`. I have been unable to figure out how after trying for three days. So I'm wondering if there is an alternate package or method to figure out the loading to add to the plot. I have to code for what needs to be done and commented how to proceed if the `BiodiversityR` package had worked.

```
library(vegan)
set.seed(111)
sp1 <- rnorm(72, mean = 4, 1)
sp2 <- rnorm(72, mean = 2, 1)
sp3 <- rnorm(72, mean = 3, 1)
sp4 <- rnorm(72, mean = 9, 1)

sp.abd <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4)


species.db <- vegdist(sp.abd, method = "bray")
species.db <- vegdist(sp.abd, method = "bray", upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
species.db[is.na(sp.abd)] <- 0
species.pcoa <- cmdscale(species.db, eig = TRUE, k = 3)

speciesREL <- sp.abd
for(i in 1:nrow(sp.abd)){
  speciesREL[i, ] = sp.abd[i, ] / sum(sp.abd[i, ])
}

library(BiodiversityR)
species.pcoa <- add.spec.scores(species.pcoa, speciesREL, method = "pcoa.scores")


##PLOT PCOA
explainvar1 <- round(species.pcoa $eig[1] / sum(species.pcoa $eig), 3) * 100
explainvar2 <- round(species.pcoa $eig[2] / sum(species.pcoa $eig), 3) * 100
explainvar3 <- round(species.pcoa $eig[3] / sum(species.pcoa $eig), 3) * 100
sum.eig <- sum(explainvar1, explainvar2, explainvar3)

df1 <- data.frame(species.pcoa$points)

rda.plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=X1, y=X2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 3, alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dotted") +
  coord_fixed()  +
  theme_classic()

rda.plot

##Adding lines
#df2 <- data.frame(species.pcoa$cproj)

# rda.biplot <- rda.plot +
#   geom_segment(data=df2, aes(x=0, xend=X1, y=0, yend=X2), 
#                color="black", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.01,"npc"))) +
#   geom_text(data=df2, 
#             aes(x=X1,y=X2,label=rownames(df2),
#                 hjust=0.5*(1-sign(X1)),vjust=0.5*(1-sign(X2))), 
#             color="black", size=4) + 
# rda.biplot
```

For example, without any transformation adding the "most influential" species looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: Also, a complete bonus to the question. I am trying to actually calculate zero-adjusted Bray Curtis Index. I have no idea how to go about it in R. If anyone has any ideas, please comment below.

Comment: Can't you download the [package source](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=BiodiversityR) and use the code? The license is the GPL-2 so give credits and share the knowledge therein.

Comment: I'm using R on a Mac (Big Sur 11.4) and R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18). I have not had trouble loading `BiodiversityR` or `Rcmdr`. The main problem I see with your code is that `X1` and `X2` are not defined anywhere.

Comment: @dcarlson It's been a problem for quite a few users and unfortunately mine is one. X1 and X2 are in the data.frame df1

Comment: @RuiBarradas I am not sure how that works. So I downloaded the package as a zip file. How do I sources it into my R code?

Comment: The source code is in directory `BiodiversityR/R`. If you see if you can adapt it to be used without `tcl-tk`. (I have never used the package so I'm not sure if this is possible, it's just an idea.)

Comment: What do you mean with "most influential species"? If you can tell that, I can implement the code (sure).

Comment: @JariOksanen I think it means adding the eigenvectors and names like in this example where the sepal width, lenth etc are added. Graph 5 & 6 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html

Comment: @JariOksanen I have added an example graph to show the loading + vector